# Debug.Log only show when running on xcode

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

Unity Debug.Log only show when I run my game on xcode.

I know Windows->Devices can show devices' log always, not only when running, but I can not see Debug.Log in that area.

How to see Debug.Log always?

Comment: What do you mean by see always? The app has to run for printing to happen, when do you want to see it?

Comment: Sorry for my bad language. When I install my game and connect my device to xcode, the "Windows->Devices" can not show "Debug.Log". That is what I mean always. But now I can see "Debug.Log" only when I use "Product -> Run".